# How to execute tens of thousands of async operations per second that each have a three second wait time?

Tags: java, node.js, concurrency

I need to execute tens of thousands of IO bound operations per second in one application that each have a 3 second delay. In node.js this can be trivially accomplished as follows:

```
var events = require('events');
var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

var count = 0;

var connectHandler = function connected() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        count++;
        console.log('task complete ' + count);
    }, 3000);
}

for (var i = 0; i < 30000; i++) {
    eventEmitter.on('mockedIOTask', connectHandler);
}

eventEmitter.emit('mockedIOTask');
```

How can this be accomplished in a Java application? I have tried the following but it only executes 3 tasks at a time (for obvious reasons):

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        for (int i = 0; i < 30000; i++) {
            final int count = i;
            ForkJoinPool.commonPool().submit(() -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    System.out.println("task complete" + count);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            });
        }
        // Keep the program alive
        try {
            Thread.sleep(50000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like a 3 second timeout not 3 second delay. Each of the tasks is only executed in a single thread in Node.js. It's not clear what either program is trying to do.

Comment: The applications are mocking an IO bound task and then performing some operation after the IO bound task has completed (in this case, printing to console). I want to know how to mimic the behavior of the node.js application in a java application.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute 30K tasks after 3 seconds using a ScheduledExecutorService

```
ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
List<Future<?>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 30000; i++) {
    final int count = i;
    tasks.add(ses.submit(() -> System.out.println("task complete" + count)));
}
for (Future f : tasks) f.get();
ses.shutdown();
```

If you want to add IO bound operations, I would start with blocking ones, before migrating to using a library like netty to handle the non-blocking IO.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Each runnable will be performing some IO bound task and then do an operation after the IO task. Mocking the task in your code by adding `Thread.sleep(3000);` to the runnable reduces your code to one task per 3 seconds being executed.

Comment: @newToScala correct, this is where you need to use more threads and/or non blocking operations. The best way of doing this depends on your use case.

Comment: The real world application needs to perform 30,000 different DB reads per second and then print the result of the DB read. My unix environment is limited to 10,000 threads (which seems to be a dangerous number of threads for one application).

Comment: @newToScala you are likely to find your DB can't handle this many queries at once. I would start with one thread/connection and add one thread at a time to see what the DB can actually handle.

Comment: The DB has been tested and can handle more than 30k reads per second.

Comment: 30k reads per second is something completely different from 30k _concurrent_ reads at the same instant.

Comment: This is veering off course. Let's assume it is API calls or any IO bound operation. The DB isn't the issue. How can a Java app mimic the node JS app?

Comment: First thing you need is async APIs for everything you do. For low-level network IO there's Netty, but for database queries there's nothing. BTW threads are a quite cheap resource. You shouldn't be afraid of raising your OS limit to 100,000 or even 1,000,000.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik java 9 will have async DB. Though in this case the DB probably can't handle more than 10 at once.

Comment: You mean "10k at once"? Yes, it may accept 10,000 connections, but there's no way it will actually run 10,000 queries. They'll just get queued up, which could have been done client-side and spared a lot of resource wastage.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik a DB can easily queue that many connections but the point at which a DB doesn't get any more throughput and might actually get slower is less than some might think.